# Is this code thread safe

Tags: multithreading, delphi, thread-safety, vcl

```
// experimental code
procedure TFormMain.MyThumbnailProvider( const Path: Unicodestring; Width,
 Height: Integer; out Bitmap: TBitmap );
var
   AExtension: string;
   ARect: TRect;
begin
  AExtension := LowerCase( ExtractFileExt( Path ) );
  if AExtension = '.wmf' then
  begin
    ARect.Left := 0;
    ARect.Top := 0;
    ARect.Right := Width;
    ARect.Bottom := Height;
    Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile( Path ); // added at design time to form
    Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
    Bitmap.Width := Width;
    Bitmap.Height := Height;
    Bitmap.Canvas.StretchDraw( ARect, Image1.Picture.Graphic );
  end;
end;
```

**Edited**

```
procedure TFormMain.MyThumbnailProvider( const Path: Unicodestring; Width, Height: Integer; out Bitmap: TBitmap );
var
  ARect: TRect;
  APicture: TPicture;
  AExtension: string;
begin
  // experimental code
  if FileExists( Path ) then
  begin
    AExtension := LowerCase( ExtractFileExt( Path ) );
    if AExtension = '.wmf' then
    begin
      ARect.Left := 0;
      ARect.Top := 0;
      ARect.Right := Width;
      ARect.Bottom := Height;
      APicture := TPicture.Create;
      try
        APicture.LoadFromFile( Path );
        Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
        Bitmap.SetSize( Width, Height );
        Bitmap.IgnorePalette := True;
        Bitmap.PixelFormat := pf24bit;
        Bitmap.Transparent := False;
        Bitmap.Canvas.Lock; **// New**
        try
          Bitmap.Canvas.StretchDraw( ARect, APicture.Graphic );
        finally
          Bitmap.Canvas.Unlock;  **// New!**
        end;
      finally
        APicture.Free;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

This seems to fix the drawing problem completely!  Apparently you have to lock and unlock the canvas when using Draw or StretchDraw because in a thread, the DC of its Bitmap.canvas is sometimes cleared due to the GDI Object Caching mechanism in graphics.pas.

See http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=55871

Comment: You are asking about thread safety but I don't see concurrent threads in your question. Why are you bother about thread safety?

Comment: Have you heard of Jim Kueneman's [VirtualShellTools library](http://mustangpeak.net/)? It does a very good job at displaying files the way Explorer does, and it even handles thumbnail view.

Comment: Rob.  Yes I used Jim Kueneman's VirtualShellTools library for many years.  It was very well done, until about Delphi 2009 or 2010.  Since then I can not get it to install and as far as I know it has not been updated in some time.  Even Jim's user groups have nearly no activity in over a year.  I think Jim is busy on other things now... Plasmatech seems to have discontinued shell development as well, leaving only JamShellBrower as the only viable vcl shell left... which is very good by the way, has good support as well as recent updates.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, because of this:

```
Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile( Path );
/// [...]
Bitmap.Canvas.StretchDraw( ARect, Image1.Picture.Graphic );
```

You can only work with the VCL controls from the main VCL thread.

Comment: But if he created a new `TPicture` object for use by the thread, he could use that to load the file instead of the one provided by the `TImage` control, and that would work, right?

Comment: Yes, the TPicture object seems to be thread safe but in a folder with 12 wmf files, 3 are not correct?  See the screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

In general VCL code is not thread safe, and this applies to the majority of VCL objects available for use.

You said:

> This seems to be threadsafe because no exceptions are produced in the thread, but the images seem to be partially blank or not drawing correctly?

"No exceptions" are not an indication of 'thread safety'. That's the same as saying "I drove to work, and didn't crash, so my car is crash proof."

Threading issues are highly timing dependent, and manifest themselves in a variety of ways - not just exceptions. The important thing to remember is that threading issues can exist as latent defects for months before anything untoward happens. And even so, they are typically very difficult to reproduce with any measure of consistency.

- You're actually lucky if you get exceptions with threading issues, the other problems can be more difficult to track, or even realise they're occuring.
- You can get deadlocks, but if it's in a background thread, you might not even realise it.
- Incorrect behaviour (as you're reporting), typically due to race conditions in which:

  - Some code will interact with an object while it's in an inconsistent state - typically resulting in highly unpredictable behaviour.
  - Data being incorrectly 'discarded' because one routines changes immediately overwrite another's.
- Poor performance; yes, poorly implemented muti-threaded solutions can severely reduce performance.

When you say "images seem to be partially blank or not drawing correctly", an important question is: Is it always the same images misbehaving, in the same way?  If so, then the issue might simply be that the control you're using to load the images is having a problem with those specific files.

Are you actually running multiple threads? I did't see anything in your code to indicate as such.
Have you tried running single-threaded to confirm whether it really is a threading issue?

---

**EDIT**
Then the simplest solution will probably be:

- Define a custom message const on which you can implement a message handler.
- Implement a message handler for the message
- Modify your existing `procedure TFormMain.MyThumbnailProvider` so that it can synchronise with the VCL Main Thread, and pass the work on to the synchronised handler.

The following will call your custom handler in the VCL main thread, and wait for a return.

```
procedure TFormMain.MyThumbnailProvider( const Path: Unicodestring; 
  Width, Height: Integer; out Bitmap: TBitmap );
var
  LThumnailData: TThumbnailData; //Assuming an appropriately defined record
begin
  LThumbnailData.FPath := Path;
  LThumbnailData.FWidth := Width;
  LThumbnailData.FHeight := Height;
  LThumbnailData.FBitmap := nil;
  SendMessage(Self.Handle, <Your Message Const>, 0, Longint(@LThumbnailData));
  Bitmap := LThumbnailData.FBitmap;
end;
```

---

**EDIT2**
More sample code requested:
Declaring the message const.

```
const
  //Each distinct message must have its own unique ref number.
  //It's recommended to start at WM_APP for custom numbers.
  MSG_THUMBNAILINFO = WM_APP + 0;
```

Declaring the record type. Really easy, but you need the pointer too.

```
type
  PThumbnailData = ^TThumbnailData;
  TThumbnailData = record
    FPath: Unicodestring;
    FWidth, FHeight: Integer;
    FBitmap: TBitmap;
  end;
```

Declaring the message handler.

```
procedure MSGThumbnailInfo(var Message: TMessage); message MSG_THUMBNAILINFO;
```

Implementing the message handler.

```
procedure TForm3.MSGThumbnailInfo(var Message: TMessage);
var
  LThumbnailData: PThumbnailData;
begin
  LThumbnailData := Pointer(Message.LParam);

  //The rest of your code goes here.
  //Don't forget to set LThumbnailData^.FBitmap before done.

  Message.Result := 0;
  inherited;
end;
```

Comment: When you say "images seem to be partially blank or not drawing correctly", an important question is: Is it always the same images misbehaving, in the same way?

Comment: "When you say "images seem to be partially blank or not drawing correctly", an important question is: Is it always the same images misbehaving, in the same way?" 

No... different thumbnails are not drawn correctly each time I select a folder.  Sometimes nearly all the thumbanils are drawing correctly while at other times a different set of thumbnails are drawing incorrectly.

Yes multiple threads are running.  The reason you did not see the code is because the code is in JamShellBrowser which I can not share.

Comment: How do you define TThumbnailData and write the message?

We have found that Bitmap.Canvas.StretchDraw( ARect, APicture.Graphic ); may be causing the problem.  Is Bitmap.Canvas.StretchDraw threadsafe?

Comment: See latest edit.  Problem solved with Canvas.Lock and Canvas.Unlock.

Comment: @Bill: Yes, the problem you've **noticed** may be solved, but as already point out, that doesn't mean there aren't any more threading issues. For that you have to carefully examine the code you're calling. E.g. `APicture := TPicture.Create;` Looking at the implementation of `TPicture.Create`, this call can perform a lazy initialisation of 2 global objects. If the first call is from multiple threads simultaneously, you will probably get a small memory leak. Lucky that's not too bad, but there are plenty of things happening in the VCL between that line and the point where you lock the Canvas.

Comment: Thanks Craig.  I will try to implement some of your code.  Thanks for taking the time to provide it.  As you may guess I am not too vell versed in threaded code.  Thanks again for your help.  So far in my testing I have not seen any thread-like errors but then again I have not tried to view a folder with hundreds of files either.